# Is there a way to run excel code in sql or run small datasets in excel and export to SQL automatically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I'm perfectly happy with excel; I know the codes and I find the interface very intuitive. The only problem I have now is that I have lots of formulas in several columns, which are linked to other excel files and am tracking sales over time. Currently I have 1500+ rows of data and sometimes Excel has trouble to calculate all the necessary codes and I need a way to make sure that into the future, when there are 10000+ or more rows, it is possible to run the code without Excel stopping/freezing. My boss says using SQL should help. However, I am unfamiliar with it and know that excel and SQL can be used similarly.

Ultimately, I want to know if I can run the excel code in SQL or if I can calculate small datasets (sets that are pulled periodically) in excel and them export to SQL automatically instead of having to go through the wizard for importing data. Also, I would need to attach the small datasets into the large one. Any ideas other than just learning SQL? This needs to be accessible to many people who don't know SQL so simply learning SQL isn't too helpful.

Comment: It's all kind of backwards sounding, what are the people who need to have the data accessible doing with it? Running other calculations?  On large chunks of it at a time?  Putting all of the data in SQL and running calculations therein, then offering up the calculated results to people in Excel seems like the way to go to me.

Comment: The reason that I'd like to use excel is that I have many complicated formulas in Excel that I'm not sure how to translate into SQL. I have about a week to complete this project, so trying to find a work around would be nice. @Goat CO, sorry, I was unclear. I need a solution that can be automated/other people can replicate with little knowledge of SQL since I will no longer be able to help them after a week.

Comment: If Excel is struggling with the calculations it sounds like a db could be a good option, but it depends on what calculations are being performed, and setting up a process in a week and training others on it might not be feasible.  Excel 2013 has expanded support for larger datasets, and has some good options for interfacing with external data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with `Excel` and its formulas, it won't be too arduous for you to pick up on `SQL`.  In addition to that, I can copy and paste outputs from `SQL Sever` into `Excel` sheets that have a graph auto-built (since I use Express) and it's a simple copy-and-paste into an `Excel` sheet.

While I don't know all your calculations, I haven't seen `Excel` be able to do something that `SQL` couldn't do and when you consider the benefit of indexing among the freedom to organize your data how you want (and have saved stored procedures), a switch might only be temporarily inconvenient while you pick up on `SQL`, and after that, you'll easily produce what you need.

> Ultimately, I want to know if I can run the excel code in SQL

Not always exactly identical, but you can run similar structured code.  For instance:

```
SELECT AVG(Sales) "AverageSales"
FROM Sales
```

VERSUS

```
=AVERAGE(A2:A2000)
```

or

```
SELECT (((DollarToday - DollarYesterday)/DollarYesterday)*100) AS "DollarDelta"
FROM USD
```

VERSUS

```
=(((A2-A1)/A1)*100)
```